# Getting error when upload file in drupal 7

Tags: file-upload, drupal-7

I have just started learning Drupal 7, and want to upload a file using a custom form. But when I upload file it generates below error.
[image]

Here is my code.

```
function custom_form_form($form,&$form_state) {
     $form = array();
         $form['photos'] = array(
         '#title' => t('Image'),
         '#type' => 'file',
         '#name' => 'files[photos]',
     );
     $form['submit'] = array(
          '#value' => 'Submit',
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#name' => 'submit',
     );                                    
     $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_function';
     return $form;
}

function custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state){

     $validators = array(
         'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg png gif'),
     );
     //Save file
     $file_destination = "public://Photos/";
     $file = file_save_upload('photos', $validators, $file_destination,FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
     if(isset($file->uri)){ //if you need this file to be not temporary
          $file->status = 1;
          file_save($file);
     }
     if ($file) {
          $file_content = file_get_contents($file->filepath);
          echo $file_content;
     }
     else{
         print_r(form_set_error('photos', 'Could not upload file.'));
     }
}
```

I don't know where I am making a mistake !!!

Comment: post on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `file_save_upload()` in the [Drupal 7 API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7), it seems that the 'file' object returned by that function have no 'filepath' member. You may want to try something like `$file_content = file_get_contents(file_create_url($file->uri));` instead.